# Is a subspace of functions that essentially depend only on one variable closed?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

Let $S$ be the subspace

$$\left\{f\in L^p( I^2)|\exists g\in L^p( I), f(x,y)=g(x), \mbox{a.e. } (x,y)\in I^2\right\}.$$

Is $S$ closed under the $L^p$ norm?

If I find some $h$ in the dual $L^q$ ($p+q=1$) to separate a point and a convex set in this subspace $S$, could I show that $h$ is  also essentially depend only on one variable?

---

I think the first step would  be to suppose there exists $\{f_n\}_n \subset S$ such that $f_n\to  L^p\phantom{0}  f\in L^p(I^2)$. Then there exists $\{g_n\}_n \subset    L^p(I^2)$ such that $g_n\to L^p \phantom{0}  f\in L^p(I^2)$? Is it right?

Then, we have  for any $\epsilon>0$ and any $n\geq N$,  $||g_n-f||_p\leq \epsilon$. Now suppose $f\notin S$. There is  positive measure $E$ in $I^2$ that $f=h(x,y)$ on $E$? We can choose  $f(x,y)=g_n(x)$ on $I^2\setminus E$, then $||g_n-f||_p>\epsilon$ and we have contradiction?

Comment: Just to clarify: your functions are those that are constant in the second variable, right?

Comment: I guess he means the functions $f$ which are equal, when hold constant  in the second variable.

Comment: Yes. I mean the functions that depend only on $x_1$ and not on $x_2$.

Comment: I'd feel better if you defined $S$ to consist of functions $f\in L^p(I^2)$ for which there exists a $g\in L^p(I)$ such that $f(x,y) = g(x)$ for a.e. $(x,y)\in I^2.$

Comment: Thanks, I think it would be better to define the problem in this way. Do you have  any hints for the question?

Comment: Note $g\in L^2(I).$ Can you make a start? What's the first step in showing something is closed in a metric space?

Comment: I think it would  be a sequence in $S$ converges a point in $S$.  Suppose there exists $\{f_n\}_n \subset S$ such that $f_n\to  L^p\phantom{0}  f\in L^p(I^2)$  . Then there exists $\{g_n\}_n \subset    L^p(I^2)$ such that $g_n\to L^p \phantom{0}  f\in L^p(I^2)$? Is it right?

Comment: Then, we have  for any $\epsilon>0$ and any $n\geq N$,  $||g_n-f||_p\leq \epsilon$. Now suppose $f\notin S$. There is  postive measure $E$ in $I^2$ that $f=h(x,y)$ on $E$? We can choose  $f(x,y)=g_n(x)$ on $I^2\setminus E$, then $||g_n-f||_p>\epsilon$ and we have contradiction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $(f_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is a sequence of elements of $S$ converging in $\mathbb L^p(I^2)$ to some function $f$. Then we extract a subsequence $(f_{n_k})_{n\geqslant 1}$ which converges almost everywhere to $f$. There exists a function $g_{n_k}$ such that for almost every $(x,y)\in I$, $f_{n_k}(x,y)=g(x)$. Thus, for almost every $(x,y)\in I$, 
we have 
$$f(x,y)=\lim_{k\to \infty}f_{n_k}(x,y)=\lim_{k\to \infty}g_{n_k}(x).$$
Defining $g(x):=\lim_{k\to \infty}g_{n_k}(x)$ and $g(x)=0$ outside the null set where the convergence of $(f_{n_k})$ does not take place, we derive that $f\in S$.

Comment: Thanks. The answer is very helpful.

Comment: If I find some $h$ in the dual $L^q$ ($p+q=1$) to separate a point and a convex set in this subspace $S$, could I conclude that $h$ is  also essentially depend only on one variable?

Answer (score 4):

For a quick proof, observe that the map $T: L^p(I) \to L^p(I^2)$ that sends $g$ to such an $f$ is a linear map that preserves norms, so it can be thought of as an isometric embedding. An isometrically embedded image of a complete space is always closed in the ambient space.

Comment: Hi, if I know the closed unit ball in the original space is weak$^*$ compact with respect to its weak$^*$ topology, would the same set in this subspace that essentially depends on one variable also weak$^*$ compact?

Comment: I mean the intersection of the same set with a closed subspace of the original space.